# Django не отображается static изображение

Tags: python, django

Я создала свой первый учебный проект на **Django**. Планирую перенести базу данных на **PostgreSQL** и упаковать проект в **Docker**. Решила проверить работоспособность страницы *404*, т.к. я ее переопределяла. Но, у меня не отображается изображение из шаблона. Выдается ошибка:

```
Not Found: /static/programmingLanguages/images/error.png
[18/May/2022 11:26:37] "GET /static/programmingLanguages/i
mages/error.png HTTP/1.1" 404 239
```

Все, что я нашла по этому вопросу, перепробовала. Так же, я выяснила, что даже если указать url изображения из интернета, а не статический файл, изображение так же не появляется. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста. Я не понимаю почему не отображается изображение именно на этой странице, т.к. все изображения на всем сайте работают корректно.

**settings.py**

```
DEBUG = False
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = Path.cwd()/'static'
STATIC_DIR = Path.cwd()/'static'
STATICFILES_DIRS = []
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)
MEDIA_ROOT = Path.cwd()/'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

**views.py**

```
def pageNotFound(request, exception):
    return render(request, 'programmingLanguages/error.html', status=404)
```

**testsite\urls.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('programmingLanguages.urls')),
    path('martor/', include('martor.urls')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    path('captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),

] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns

handler404 = 'programmingLanguages.views.pageNotFound'
```

**error.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Page not found</title>

</head>
<body>
{% load static %}
<div class="container">
    <img class="img" src='{% static "programmingLanguages/images/error.png" %}'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Структура проекта**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Необходимо изменить файл **testsite/urls.py** следующим образом:

```
from django.views.static import serve as mediaserve

from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include, re_path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('programmingLanguages.urls')),
    path('martor/', include('martor.urls')),
    path('ckeditor/', include('ckeditor_uploader.urls')),
    path('captcha/', include('captcha.urls')),

]

if settings.DEBUG:
    import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns = [
        path('__debug__/', include(debug_toolbar.urls)),
    ] + urlpatterns
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
else:
    urlpatterns += [
        re_path(f'^{settings.MEDIA_URL.lstrip("/")}(?P<path>.*)$',
            mediaserve, {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
        re_path(f'^{settings.STATIC_URL.lstrip("/")}(?P<path>.*)$',
            mediaserve, {'document_root': settings.STATIC_ROOT})
    ]

handler404 = 'programmingLanguages.views.pageNotFound'
```

Я добавила блок `else:` в таком виде статические и медиа файлы вне режима `DEBUG`, как на локальном компьютере так и на рабочем сервере, будут браться из указанных папок.